# Client to Client Communication in OpenVpn

Tags: openvpn, pki

In client to client communication in OpenVpn, can server be separated from the network once the authentication is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.          ​           ​               ​

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I'd have thought it was bleeding obvious. A VPN is not going to work if you remove the VPN server, no matter what routing options you set on the server.